# how to add status message onto status box in facebook programmatically

Tags: iphone, facebook

i need to post message on the wall of the facebook.

for this i am fallowing this [Facebook tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app).

i need some enhancement for this tutorial that is i need place status message programmatically.

means when user login with username and password then automatically display the status message in status box.

like welcome to my facebook.

i found that this is the [url to get message box](http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php).

then how can i add status message into this box.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

(Let me add comment if any one did n't get my question)

Comment: You can try this link: http://freelance.ph/tutorials/php-and-mysql/facebook-app-basics-share-a-link/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a guess and added the message parameter. It worked! See:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=hello
```

You might consider using newer APIs as I believe this one is deprecated.

Comment: i amtrying like this,http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php/?message=%@",message.But i am getting error statically declaring objective-c class NSString